# getting records from sqlite database with ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have created a simple products table with sqlite database using ruby. I can retrieve the recors as per the normal select statement passing the product_code as a where condition.
anytime I retrieve a record I want to be able to store the record in an array and add to prices of the items selected to get the total value, just as in a online basket.
I am doing this in ruby without rails, just the console. 
exsample of the select statement

```
def select(item_code)
 item_code = item_code
 begin
   db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"
   results = db.get_first_row "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Product_code = ?",    
              item_code
   puts results.join "\s"

  rescue SQLite3::Exception => e 

  puts "Exception occured"
  puts e

ensure
db.close if db
end
```

end

thank you.

Comment: when I get the record, I want to store it in an array preferable, then add the item price lets say I do select(1), select(2), select(3), I want to display these items and then add the prices to get the total.

Comment: The result of: db.get_first_row is an array, but you are joining the array elements together using space ("\s") as a separator with: puts results.join "\s"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$prices, $index_of_price = [], 0
#index_of_price is the index of the field in your result

def select(item_code) 
  begin 
    db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db" 
    results = db.get_first_row "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Product_code = ?", item_code 
    $prices << results[$index_of_price]
  rescue
    puts $!
  ensure 
   db.close if db
  end
end 

select 1
select 2

puts "Total is #{$prices.inject(0){|sum,item| sum + item}}"
```